# Handling events on dynamically generated JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, object, scope

I have an object I created in JavaScript. Let's say it looks like this:

```
function MyObject() {
    this.secretIdea = "My Secret Idea!";
};

MyObject.prototype.load = function() {
    this.MyButton = $(document.createElement("a"));
    this.MyButton.addClass("CoolButtonClass");
    this.MyButton.click = MyButton.onButtonClick;
    someRandomHtmlObject.append(this.MyButton);
};

MyObject.prototype.onButtonClick = function(e) {
    alert(this.secretIdea);
};
```

As you can see, I have an object setup in JavaScript and, when it's loaded, it creates an anchor tag. This anchor tag as a background image in CSS (so it's not empty).

Now, I understand that the 'this' statement, when the button would actually be clicked, would fall to the scope of the MyButton element rather than the object I have created.

I have tried using call(), try() and bind() and I cannot get this to work. I need it so that, when the button is clicked, it goes back to the object's scope and not the html element's scope.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` value inside the click event handler refers to the DOM element, not to the object instance of your constructor.

You need to persist that value, also you refer to `MyButton.onButtonClick` I think you want to refer the `onButtonClick` method declared on `MyObject.prototype`:

```
MyObject.prototype.load = function() {
    var instance = this;
    //..
    this.MyButton.click(function (e) { // <-- looks like you are using jQuery
      // here `this` refers to `MyButton`
      instance.onButtonClick(e);
    });
    //...
};
```